# SSRS how to add groups to a detail row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am re-writting this because I didn't communicate my problem correctly.

Given these sample tables of data:

STUDENT: Name, DOB, Council, ClassId

CLASS: ClassId, Teacher, StudentGradeId

GRADE: StudentId, ClassId, Grade

I have made a report that looks like this:

[image]

But I need to hide the duplicate row details for Name, DOB & Council.  I am currently grouping by StudentId which groups correctly, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the duplicate student data.  It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You could using stored procedure to join 3 tables together, and only need one dataset.

Comment: Assuming I have the query side figured out, is is possible to build this report?

Comment: I would join the 3 tables into a single dataset, although the tables seem strange in their relationships. Once you have the dataset, create a matrix with Name, DOB, Council. Then add columns and a child group for classes, teacher, and grade.

Comment: Yes, like Andrew said, use matrix or table. I prefer table

Comment: I haven't put my question across correctly.  I have edited the OP, hopefully it communicates better.

Comment: @BattlFrog, In that case you have to create a Row group for each field, Name, DOB, and Council. Go through the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx).

Comment: @alejandro zuleta, THanks, that was the trick.  I was looking at it backwards, trying to group the child data.  Thanks.  You should post answer.

Comment: @BattlFrog, you're welcome I posted an answer, you can mark it as the correct answer to close positively your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid repeated rows in the `Name`, `DOB`, and `Council` columns you will have to create a Row group for each one. Go through the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx).

Let me know if this helped you.